# Windows task scheduler issue python script automation

Tags: python, windows, pandas, windows-server-2008, taskscheduler

I'm running a python script using the task scheduler. The script gets data from a database using pandas and stores them in csv.gz files.

It's running properly but there is a difference in data size when the Task Scheduler runs automatically and when it is run manually via Task scheduler run button. The manual run gets all the data, whereas automated run gets lesser data.

It runs the same script. I've checked multiple times. But unable to identify the issue.

PS: 
Using Windows Server 2008, pymssql to connect to Database

Comment: This probably isn't helpful but... Are you running under a different user?

Comment: @piRSquared i'm running as the same user.